# Class.forName() не находит класс в jar-файле проекта

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jdbc, firebird, classloader

Есть проект в ItelliJ IDEA 14.1. В нем есть каталог с используемыми библиотеками. Внутри каталога библиотеки разделены по подкаталогам: `jdbc\poi\...` . Все библиотеки добавлены в проект и отображаются в **Libraries, Modules.Dependencies**.

В дебаге в classpath присутствуют все необходимые библиотеки:

```
E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:54660,suspend=y,server=n -Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 -classpath "E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\charsets.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\deploy.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\javaws.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jce.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfr.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jfxrt.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\jsse.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\plugin.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\resources.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\rt.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;E:\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\.build\classes;**E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\jdbc\ojdbc6.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\jdbc\jaybird-2.0.1.jar;**E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\native\log4j-1.2.16.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\opencsv\opencsv-4.0.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\commons-codec-1.10.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\commons-collections4-4.1.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\curvesapi-1.04.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\poi-3.16.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\poi-ooxml-3.16.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\poi-ooxml-schemas-3.16.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\poi\xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\svnkit\svnkit-1.8.7.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\svnkit\svnkit-cli-1.8.7.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\svnkit\svnkit-javahl16-1.8.7.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\svnkit\sqljet-1.1.10.jar;E:\Projects\MyProject\lib\svnkit\sequence-library-1.0.3.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.myproject.Main
```

Последней добавлялась библиотека `jaybird-2.0.1.jar` в каталог jdbc для подключения к Firebird.

Рядом с этой библиотекой в том же каталоге лежит библиотека `ojdbc6.jar` для подключения к Oracle.

При попытке обращения к классу драйвера Oracle через `Class.forName()` (перед установкой соединения с БД) — все в порядке.

При попытке обращения к классу драйвера Firebird — ошибка:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.resource.ResourceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

Обычно в таких случаях проблема сводится к отсутствию нужного класса\библиотеки в classpath.

На этом сайте были советы прописать проблемный jar в параметрах запуска:

```
java -Djava.library.path=./lib -jar your_jar.jar
```

А так же внутри архива создать файл `java.sql.Driver` и внутри него прописать нужный класс (так сделано внутри архива `ojdbc6.jar`), но мне это не помогло.

Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: указание в VMOptions -Djdbc.drivers=org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver;oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver так же не изменяет ситуации, как и переход на новую библиотеку jaybird-3.0.3.jar

Comment: Пробовал так же без использования Class.forName(): вроде бы начиная с JDBC 4.0 загрузка драйверов происходит автоматически путем получения имени драйвера из файлов \META-INF\services\java.sql.Driver библиотек, указанных в ClassPath.
Для Oracle это сработало, для Firebird — нет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что такой класс находится в j2ee. Поэтому вам надо добавить j2ee библиотеки к classpath.

В более поздних версиях java ee есть тоже такой класс. Вы можете прочитать о нем в [apidocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/resource/ResourceException.html).

Comment: благодарю за ответ